# CodeFirst copies properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have these two models:

`UserModel`

```
[Table("user")]
public class UserModel {
    [Key]
    [Column("emailaddress")]
    public string Emailaddress { get; set; }

    [Column("firstname")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Column("lastname")]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

`ContactPersonModel`

```
[Table("contactperson")]
public class ContactPersonModel {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("firstname")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Column("lastname")]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [Column("emailaddress")]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Emailaddress { get; set; }

    [Column("phonenumber")]
    [Phone]
    public string Phonenumber { get; set; }

    public virtual UserModel Creator { get; set; }
}
```

This is the method I use to insert items in the database:

```
public async Task<ContactPersonModel> AddContactPerson(ContactPersonModel model) {
    dbmodel.ContactPerson.Add(model);
    dbmodel.Entry(model.Creator).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    if (await dbmodel.SaveChangesAsync() == 0) {
        Log.ErrorFormat("cannot add contactperson {0}", model.Emailaddress);
        throw new Exception("cannot add contactperson");
    } else {
        await dbmodel.Entry(model).ReloadAsync();
        return model;
    }
}
```

When I call the method `AddContactPerson` the properties `Firstname`, `Lastname` and `Emailaddress` get copied from the `UserModel` to the `ContactPersonModel` and overrides the values I set. How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: EF doesn't tend to copy data spontaneously. Are you sure `model` doesn't contain these values in the first place?

Comment: Jep, I am sure about this. After I made all the names unique, by prefixing the propertynames with the classname it works... So I think it copies the data or maybe tracks them in a weird way